# Haproxy get logs from docker container

Tags: haproxy

I have launched Haproxy from docker.

I need to get logs of Haproxy.

Some direction may be useful.

My haproxy.config is as follows

global

log 127.0.0.1 local0

log 127.0.0.1 local1 notice

Answer (score 6):

As you have not wirtten which version from haproxy you use I will give you the answer to the latest version 2.0.2.
You can use the following line to print the logs to stdout.

```
log stdout format raw daemon debug
```

The full option set of the log directive is documented in the doc [log](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.0/configuration.html#log)

Don't forget to add `log global` in `default`section or in every proxy section.